# pandas rolling apply return np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a custom skewness function to rolling apply, but got np.nan instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def _get_skewness(col, q=(0.05, 0.95)):
    if q[0] > 0:
        quantiles = col.quantile(q)
        col.loc[(col<quantiles[q[0]]) | (col > quantiles[q[1]])] = np.nan
    skew = col.skew(axis=0, skipna=True)
    return skew

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(40).reshape(-1, 2))

df_skew = df.rolling(20, 10).apply(_get_skewness)
print(df_skew)
```

I got the following result. I understand the first 10 rows are due to the rolling window min_period=10. Just don't get why the last few rows return np.nan as well.

```
      0    1
0   NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN
9   0.0  0.0
10  0.0  0.0
11  0.0  0.0
12  0.0  0.0
13  0.0  0.0
14  0.0  0.0
15  NaN  NaN
16  NaN  NaN
17  NaN  NaN
18  NaN  NaN
19  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: `col.loc[(col<quantiles[q[0]]) | (col > quantiles[q[1]])] = np.nan` sets some values to `NaN` which remain in the output. It's hard to determine how to fix the problem without knowing what the custom skewness is/what output is expected and why.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The custom skewness function is above. The function returns skewness with skipna=True. Why would removing the tails cause a problem?

Comment: Because if the entire series is `nan` your skew will be `nan`. And you do in fact have windows where the result from col is all `nan`.

Comment: My intention is to cutting the tails of each window. Do u mean  col.loc[(col<quantiles[q[0]]) | (col > quantiles[q[1]])] = np.nan    applies to the whole columns instead of the values in the rolling window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `loc` on `col` the actual DataFrame is being modified in each iteration. The introduction of `NaN` in the column eventually means the window becomes all `NaN`. The easiest fix (without understanding more about how the skewness is to be applied) would be to create a [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.copy.html) of `col` to work on:

```
def _get_skewness(col, q=(0.05, 0.95)):
    copy_col = col.copy()  # Make a copy so as to not overwrite future values.
    if q[0] > 0:
        quantiles = copy_col.quantile(q)
        copy_col.loc[
            (copy_col < quantiles[q[0]]) | (copy_col > quantiles[q[1]])
            ] = np.nan
    skew = copy_col.skew(axis=0, skipna=True)
    return skew
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(40).reshape(-1, 2))
df_skew = df.rolling(20, 10).apply(_get_skewness)
```

`df_skew`:

```
      0    1
0   NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN
9   0.0  0.0
10  0.0  0.0
11  0.0  0.0
12  0.0  0.0
13  0.0  0.0
14  0.0  0.0
15  0.0  0.0
16  0.0  0.0
17  0.0  0.0
18  0.0  0.0
19  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask what do you mean by "without understanding more about how the skewness is to be applied"?

Comment: All I was saying is there's likely a vectorized operation which would be many orders of magnitude faster than this operation. But that would require a stronger understanding of the skewing than I currently have.